# Why did Spring Security messages go missing in Grails production app on Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, grails, spring-security, message

I've deployed my grails app to Tomcat, and the only thing that broke is the spring-security-core messages in the login form. For example, the code

```
<g:message code="springSecurity.login.username.label" />
```

now produces the output

```
springSecurity.login.username.label
```

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: For the time being, I've replaced the message codes with custom ones.

Comment: do you use embedded plugins? are other messages working?

Comment: @crudolf: I have no idea to be honest. I just do `prod war` from sts and deploy. Other messages do work.